# Trigger.io IOS 7 splashscreen issue

Tags: ios, splash-screen, trigger.io

I have pointed this out in a previous post but in IOS 7 the splash screen hides after a second or two even when I set the splash screen to hide manually it will still show.

I have confirmed this works in IOS 6 and android by setting the splash screen to hide manually in the config's, then I never call the splash screen hide command.

The results of this test are as follows

IOS 6 - Splash screen does not hide ( As expected )

Android 2.3 - 4.1 - Splash screen does not hide ( As expected )

IOS 7.0 + ( I tested on first IOS release and most current update) Splash screen hides after a second, revealing the header and footer bars before going to the main screen. ( Not working as expected )

I looked at the logs and the command gets called but IOS 7 just seems to ignore this, to test further I removed everything from my index and just used a clean project with no other JS, just a simple "Test" in the index.html.

This test resulted in the same outcome for IOS 7+

Comment: Hmm, can't reproduce here unfortunately. Created an app, added launchimage, set "hide manually", ran in iOS 7 simulator, launch image appeared and never went away. Could you try that? Not too sure what you mean by "I looked at the logs and the command gets called", could you pastebin that log somewhere and link?

Comment: Have you tried it on an actual device? I tested on iPad 3 with 7. Let me pull the logs and maybe I can do a vid as well

Comment: Aha, can reproduce on iPad simulator actually, thanks for the extra info. I've raised a ticket.